# Help with a Join in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have the following models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :action_items
end

class ActionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :action_item_type
end

class ActionItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :action_items
end
```

And what I want to do is, for a given event, find all the action items that have an action item type with a name of "foo" (for example).  So I think the SQL would go something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM action_items a
INNER JOIN action_item_types t
ON a.action_item_type_id = t.id
WHERE a.event_id = 1
AND t.name = "foo"
```

Can anybody help me translate this into a nice active record query? (Rails 3 - Arel)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I think I solved it myself.  Here's what I did

```
e = Event.find(1)
e.action_items.joins(:action_item_type).where("action_item_types.name = ?", "foo")
```

Comment: If you wanted to make it even nicer looking you can do `e.action_items.joins(:action_item_type).where(:action_item_types => {:name => "foo"})`

Comment: I also noticed that if you pass a String, not a Symbol, to your joins, it doesn't form the query correctly.

e.g. do 
Event.joins(:action_item_type)
NOT
Event.joins("action_item_type")

Comment: Does this works in Rails4 ? `subscriptions.joins(:plan).where(:plans => { :is_free_trial => true })` return _Unknown column 'plans.is_free_trial' in 'where clause'_

Answer (score 4):

Ehm, why not define

```
has_many :action_item_types, :through => :action_items
```

and refer to

```
e.action_item_types.where(:name => "foo")
```

?

Answer (score 1):

or (as long as "name" is a unique column name)

```
e.action_items.joins(:action_item_type).where(:name => "foo")
```