# Use Ruby's select method on a Rails relation and update it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord relation of a user's previous "votes"...

```
@previous_votes = current_user.votes
```

I need to filter these down to votes only on the current "challenge", so Ruby's `select` method seemed like the best way to do that...

```
@previous_votes = current_user.votes.select { |v| v.entry.challenge_id == Entry.find(params[:entry_id]).challenge_id }
```

But I also need to update the attributes of these records, and the `select` method turns my relation into an array which can't be updated or saved!

```
@previous_votes.update_all :ignore => false
# ...
# undefined method `update_all' for #<Array:0x007fed7949a0c0>
```

**How can I filter down my relation like the select method is doing, but not lose the ability to update/save it the items with ActiveRecord?**

Poking around the Google it seems like `named_scope`'s appear in all the answers for similar questions, but I can't figure out it they can specifically accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: ass a where statement `..votes.where(challenge: params[:current_challenge_id])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `select` is not an SQL method. It fetches all records and filters them on the Ruby side. Here is a simplified example:

```
votes = Vote.scoped
votes.select{ |v| v.active? }
# SQL: select * from votes
# Ruby: all.select{ |v| v.active? }
```

Since update_all is an SQL method you can't use it on a Ruby array. You can stick to performing all operations in Ruby or move some (all) of them into SQL.

```
votes = Vote.scoped
votes.select{ |v| v.active? }
# N SQL operations (N - number of votes)
votes.each{ |vote| vote.update_attribute :ignore, false }
# or in 1 SQL operation
Vote.where(id: votes.map(&:id)).update_all(ignore: false)
```

If you don't actually use fetched votes it would be faster to perform the whole select & update on SQL side:

```
Vote.where(active: true).update_all(ignore: false)
```

While the previous examples work fine with your `select`, this one requires you to rewrite it in terms of SQL. If you have set up all relationships in Rails models you can do it roughly like this:

```
entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
current_user.votes.joins(:challenges).merge(entry.challenge.votes)
# requires following associations:
# Challenge.has_many :votes
# User.has_many :votes
# Vote.has_many :challenges
```

And Rails will construct the appropriate SQL for you. But you can always fall back to writing the SQL by hand if something doesn't work.

Comment: This gives me `Unknown column 'votes.challenge_id' in 'where clause': SELECT 'votes'.* FROM 'votes'  WHERE 'votes'.'challenge_id' = 7`. Any ideas?

Comment: It is difficult to suggest not knowing your DB schema. If you can write raw SQL for your select I can help you translate it into ActiveRecord. Alternatively, you can go with the first way unless you find it really slow.

Comment: What if I sent you my schema file?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do something like:

```
@entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])    
@previous_votes = Vote.joins(:entry).where(entries: { id: @entry.id, challenge_id: @entry.challenge_id })
```

Comment: That gives me `Unknown column 'votes.user_id' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: It's the joins that does it.

Comment: And I did fix the lack of a closing `)` at the end of your first line there.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo, fixed. Votes don't have a user_id?

Comment: They do. But I think the query should be `'vote'.'user_id'` not `'votes'.'user_id'` since if you look at the whole query it uses singular everywhere else. Not sure how to modify the ActiveRecord syntax to make the correct SQl query though.

Comment: Whoops, think the where clause is incorrect. I believe `entry` should be plural. Updated in my answer.

Comment: There is the full error: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'votes.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'votes' entries WHERE 'votes'.'user_id' = 1 AND 'entries'.'challenge_id' = 7`

Comment: You have `has_many :votes` in your User model? TBH, not positive what the issue is. I'd make sure that the model relations are correct and then play with the plurality of `entries` in the above query (both places).

Comment: I'm right across the river in Vancouver btw, nice to meet you! :P

Comment: Nice to meet you! I have `has_many :votes` in the user model. Thanks for trying. If you can, upvote the question for exposure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4280345/716039 <-- not to beat a dead horse, but that SO answer does what I'm attempting to do here. Was wondering if you might need to something different than `current_user.votes`, such as `Vote.joins('entry').where(user_id: current_user.id, ...`

Answer (score 2):

Use `collection_select` instead of `select`. `collection_select` is specifically built on top of `select` to return `ActiveRecord` objects and not an array of strings like you get with `select`.

```
@previous_votes = current_user.votes.collection_select { |v| v.entry.challenge_id == Entry.find(params[:entry_id]).challenge_id }
```

This should return `@previous_votes` as an array of objects

EDIT: Updating this post with another suggested way to return those AR objects in an array

```
@previous_votes = current_user.votes.collect {|v| records.detect { v.entry.challenge_id == Entry.find(params[:entry_id]).challenge_id}}
```

Comment: `undefined method 'collection_select' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f93b1900438>`

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems `collection_select` is built on top of Rails' select method, not Ruby's, which do very different things.

Comment: @JacksonGariety Just a stab in the dark, cannot test it right now but hope it puts us on the right track. `@previous_votes = current_user.votes.collect {|v| records.detect { v.entry.challenge_id == Entry.find(params[:entry_id]).challenge_id}}`

Answer (score 2):

A nice approach this is to use [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).  In your case, you can set this up the scope as follows:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_challenge, lambda do |challenge_id|
    joins(:entry).where("entry.challenge_id = ?", challenge_id)
  end
end
```

Then your code for getting current votes will look like:

```
challenge_id = Entry.find(params[:entry_id]).challenge_id
@previous_votes = current_user.votes.for_challenge(challenge_id)
```

Comment: Are you referring to named_scope? If I use `scope` is gives me `tried to create Proc object without a block`. Named_scopes seem to have been made obsolete in Rails 3.

Comment: Edit: That error was actually caused by using `do..end` instead of `{}`. But now I get this: `Unknown column 'entry.challenge_id'` Any ideas?

Comment: What if you replace `entry.challenge_id` with `entries.challenge_id`?

Comment: Could you post the relevant portion of your model?  It's possible I've misunderstood some portion of your model.

Comment: Also, with my code above, try running current_user.votes.for_challenge(challenge_id).to_sql and see what it generates.  Maybe you can figure out where the discrepancy is.